# How do you remove IPropertyStorage automatically added LOCALE property?

Tags: c++, ipropertystorage

According to the Remarks section for the [IPropertyStorage::WriteMultiple Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

> When a new property set is created, the special codepage (Property ID 1) and Locale ID (Property ID 0x80000000) properties are written to the property set automatically.

However, I would like for my PropertySet to omit the LOCALE ID.  I have tried

```
specs[0].ulKind = PRSPEC_PROPID;
specs[0].propid = PID_LOCALE;
//specs[0].lpwstr = 0;
hr = pPropStorage->DeleteMultiple(1, specs);
```

But this fails with

> 0x80030057 Invalid parameter error

How do I omit this unwanted Property ID?  I have tried doing an `IPropertyStorage::Commit()` before and after.  But the same error is produced when calling `DeleteMultiple()`.

NOTE: I had tried with and without specs[0].lpwstr = 0; but that was stupid because it is a "union" with propid, so writing them both changes the first.  But it was still failing when setting only propid = PID_LOCALE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the DeleteMultiple right after the Create.